# what is the equivalent command 'end' of Matlab in python?

Tags: python, matlab, indexing

When I work in Matlab, I use the refer to the last element of a vector with 'end'. For example:

```
A(1, end)
```

where A is a 2x2 matrix.

Can you tell me what is the equaivalent command in python? For example, I have the following variable, as an element of a list of strings:

```
dataList[loc] = ['%Case study: test\n']
```

so the last element should be '\n'

Answer (score 7):

That would be using index `[-1]`.

```
A[0][-1]
```

Negative indices start at `[-1]` and increment from the back of the sequence.